# Can't Find Area to Input Email Address to Send Contact Form To

Tags: forms, email, contacts

I got this form from one of the free templates. Basic form.

Where I should input the email address to send the form to ?

```
$("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    // handle the invalid form...
    formError();
    submitMSG(false, "Did you fill in the form properly?");
} else {
    // everything looks good!
    event.preventDefault();
    submitForm();
}
});


function submitForm(){
// Initiate Variables With Form Content
var name = $("#name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var msg_subject = $("#msg_subject").val();
var message = $("#message").val();


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/form-process.php",
    data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&msg_subject=" + msg_subject + "&message=" + message,
    success : function(text){
        if (text == "success"){
            formSuccess();
        } else {
            formError();
            submitMSG(false,text);
        }
    }
});
}

function formSuccess(){
$("#contactForm")[0].reset();
submitMSG(true, "Message Submitted!")
}

function formError(){
    $("#contactForm").removeClass().addClass('shake 
animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd 
oanimationend animationend', function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
    });
}

function submitMSG(valid, msg){
    if(valid){
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center tada animated text-success";
    } else {
    var msgClasses = "h3 text-center text-danger";
    }
    $("#msgSubmit").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  If you mean that the input box for the email address isn't showing, you'll need to include your HTML as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, JavaScript doesn't actually send the email. You're posting the user's Name, Email, and message to a PHP form, which will then do the work of sending the email. So you should have a place in the PHP form to input the email that will then receive the messages.

You link in your AJAX POST to url: `php/form-process.php`

Comment: Sigh. I can't believe I was looking at this and completely forgot about the php file. I had mistaken it. Thank you very much for the help! Sigh...